# Почему деструктуризация не работает в Proxy?

Tags: javascript, объекты

```
function getBadge(firstname, lastname) {
  const target = {
    firstname,
    lastname,
    fullname: `${firstname} ${lastname}`,
  }

  const handler = {
    set(target, property, value, receiver) {
      if (property === "firstname" || property === "lastname") {
        target[property] = value
        target.fullname = `${target.firstname} ${target.lastname}`
      }
      if (property === "fullname") {
        target[property] = value
        [target.firstname, target.lastname] = value.split(' ') // это не работает
      }
      return true
    }
  }
  return new Proxy(target, handler)
}

const badge = getBadge("foo", "bar")
badge.fullname = "Eric Bachman"
console.log(badge) // выводит {firstname: 'foo', lastname: 'bar', fullname: ['Eric', 'Bachman']} вместо {firstname: 'Eric', lastname: 'Bachman', fullname: 'Eric Bachman'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хоть javaScript и не требует явного завершения строки кода, однако себя лучше учить делать это!

Возьмите за правило - строка кода закончилась, добавляется символ **;**

Ваш код при проверке на fullname интерпритатор читал так

```
target[property] = value[target.firstname, target.lastname] = value.split(' ')
```

```js
function getBadge(firstname, lastname) {
  const target = {
    firstname,
    lastname,
    fullname: `${firstname} ${lastname}`,
  }
  console.log(target)

  const handler = {
    set(target, property, value, receiver) {
      if (property === "firstname" || property === "lastname") {
        target[property] = value
        target.fullname = `${target.firstname} ${target.lastname}`
      }
      if (property === "fullname") {
        target[property] = value;
        [target.firstname, target.lastname] = value.split(' ') // А теперь работает
      }
      return true
    }
  }
  return new Proxy(target, handler)
}

const badge = getBadge("foo", "bar")
badge.fullname = "Eric Bachman"
console.log(badge)
```